# Applying android app icon in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, icons

I have started with Android Studio a few months before. I have found many good things and a few bad as compared to eclipse. I would like to know if there is a shortcut or easy way to change the app icon...like the Eclipse IDE offers automatically... or we still need to copy and paste the various icons (hdpi, mdpi, xxhdpi) manually to the respective directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click drawable -> New -> Image Asset -> Asset Type: Action Bar and Tab Icons. Image file: image_path, Resource Name: how_youre_image_will_be_called -> Next -> Finish

Done

This will add 4 different sizes of your image so that it will fit depending the device size (phone, tablet...)

Answer (score 0):

Using [Android Drawable Importer Plugin](https://github.com/winterDroid/android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin) you can add an option to Android Studio to import drawables in different resolutions from Android Icons.